# can't export class from dll, vs2010, c++

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, dll, export

I wrote a library with the following two classes. Visual Studio has no problems with the first class, but errors on the second one. I have no idea why. Any thoughts?

First Class:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) C_RGBImage: public C_Matrix<S_RGB>
{
public:
    C_RGBImage( S_Size<long> &A_rSize = S_Size<long>(0, 0)): C_Matrix(A_rSize){}

    bool  SaveBMP( std::wstring A_rFileName );
    bool  LoadBMP( std::wstring A_rFileName );

    bool  SaveJPEG( std::wstring A_rFileName, int A_iQuality = 85 );
    bool  LoadJPEG( std::wstring A_rFileName );
};
```

Second Class:

```
class __declspec(dllexport) C_RGBAImage: public C_Matrix<S_RGBA>
{
public:
    C_RGBAImage( S_Size<long> &A_rSize = S_Size<long>() ): C_Matrix(A_rSize){}

    bool SaveBMP( std::wstring &A_rFileName );
    bool LoadBMP( std::wstring &A_rFileName );

    bool LoadBMPFromResource( HINSTANCE A_hInstance, long A_lBitmapID );
};
```

Comment: Do you get any error when building? What does it mean when you say you can't export the second class?

Comment: The differences seem to be: 1) you're not initialising S_Size in the second, 2) you're passing strings by reference (did you mean const reference?), 3) you've changed the last two methods in a way that shouldn't be relevant. Is that correct? Can we see the error messages you're getting from the export, or the incorrect export table you're seeing?

Comment: if everything is fine, then where is the problem?

Comment: program to import second class say me this LoadBMPFromResource@C_RGBAImage@@QAE_NPAUHINSTANCE_
@©J©Z don't found in  DLL imlib.dll

Comment: Can you post the header file (C_RGBAImage.h) you used in the second application to import the class?

Comment: [link](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/53230789/C_RGBAImage.h)

Comment: [picture program show me](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/53230789/picture.PNG)

Comment: When you are exporting the class (in the imlib.dll project), you need to use `__declspec(dllexport)`. When you are importing the class (in the smartwb.exe project) you need to use `__declspec(dllimport)`. Are you doing that?

Comment: i try. this is not help.

Comment: Usually when you export a class, you use the same header in both projects, using a macro to substitute between `__declspec(dllexport)` and `__declspec(dllimport)` depending in which project you are on. Try to follow [this tutorial](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28969/HowTo-Export-C-classes-from-a-DLL). In your case, make sure that the definition of function LoadBMPFromResource is the same in both header files. I suspect it is different.

Comment: [two picture which say more...](http://dl.dropbox.com/u/53230789/picture2.png)

Comment: i am just delete project and create it again and it work! :) i don't know why :)

Answer (score 0):

I guess that you call the LoadBMPFromResource with different parameters.